# Como resolver XAMMP virtual host “Access forbidden!” erro em MAC OS Sierra 10.12.6?

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

Acabei de instalar uma versão do XAMPP [xampp-osx-5.5.38-3-installer.dmg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Mac%20OS%20X/5.5.38/).

Em seguida segui as [instruções](http://localhost/dashboard/docs/configure-vhosts.html) para setar um virtual host. Ativei `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` e criei `127.0.0.1 md-test.com` dentro de `/etc/hosts`.

Então quando eu escrevo `md-test.com` sou redirecionado para `md-test.com/dashboard/`, como o esperado. Sou redirecionado para o diretório htdocs de xampp e carrega o dashboard.

Em `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs` criei uma pasta chamada `md` `drwxrwxr-x   3 root    admin     102 21 Aug 12:02 md`, onde tenho um arquivo index.php (echo "testok";).

Para o arquivo httpd-vhosts.conf isso foi o que eu fiz:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/md/"
       ServerName md-test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Agora quando eu rodo `md-test.com/` não sou redirecionado para `md-test.com/dashboard/` ou mesmo usando o `localhost` que não me redireciona para `localhost/dashboard/`. Apenas mostra um erro:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

md-test.com
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.5.38 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Usei o visual studio para editar os arquivos.

Agora mesmo quando eu deleto as mudanças que fiz no `httpd-vhosts.conf` continuo com o erro. E isso acontece para qualquer acesso no apache de qualquer url.

Chequei as permissões de `httpd-vhosts.conf` e continua a mesma de antes.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   1489 22 Aug 11:44 httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Alguma idéia do que seja esse erro?

UPDATE:
Encontrei um possível erro:
Quando eu faço o setup do vhosts dentro do **httpd.conf** `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. mesmo quando uso full path (`Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`)  ainda tenho o erro.

Answer (score -1):

Não utilizo o XAMPP mas suspeito que seja a não especificação do `AllowOverride`

**segue exemplo:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName meusite.local
    DocumentRoot "F:\Projets\Web\site"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "F:\Projets\Web\site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Sugiro que **não** use:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*Uma vez que permite todo o acesso a toda a unidade que você instalou o XAMPP(Apache), se essa é a unidade C: \ você está fazendo a vida de hackers mais fácil!*

Comment: Oi @teliz, acho que o problema está antes mesmo da configuração do  vhost. Quando eu faço 'Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf' em httpd.conf.

Comment: hum.. tem alguma coisa no Log do apache ?